# How to determine Storage type? Session- or LocalStorage?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, local-storage, session-storage

I have a `variable` of type `Storage` - this is what `variable.constructor.name` says. How can I now determine is it `localStorage` or `sessionStorage`? I just need the name.

[image: localStorage / sessionsStorage.constructor.name]

Example code:

```
class WebStorage {
  constructor(public storage: Storage) {}

  public getStorageName(): 'LocalStorage' | 'SessionStorage' {
     // how to return proper name?
  }
}
```

Comment: where did you get `Storage` type ? never heard of it :3

Comment: Can you show us how do you get `variable` ? do you get it from a library for example ?

Comment: @niceman, it's actually an interface provided by Typescript, but the `Storage` function exists in web browsers

Comment: ahhh you should add typescript tag instead of javascript

Comment: Not really, as the types information are lost in compilation process. I've added an example

Comment: Just compare it `storage === window.localStorage`?

Comment: @zerkms, well... Yeah, that's a solution! You can add an answer, thanks :D

Comment: @DanielKucal you're using the TypeScript language, why don't you use the `enums` instead of strings for the storage type: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html it would be better for you program design.

Comment: @MatthewTipton, I need the data just for displaying and it's a bit tricky to get `enum`'s name. I can set the type to limited strings (like in the question), what I think is enough...

Comment: @DanielKucal As you wish, I can only say, that it would be better to define readonly property `Type` in `WebStorage` class and using the getter you may get the enum value. As for me, it's better, than using strings/integers for such aims, because of more pretty program design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can simply compare it:

```
return storage === window.localStorage ? 'LocalStorage' : 'SessionStorage';
```